# Javascript - Calculating square root of an cylinder

Tags: javascript, square-root

I want to write a program that calculates the square root of a cylinder. Result is too high, when I calculate it somewhere else.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate(){
    var d = document.getElementById('d')
    var v = document.getElementById('v');
    var height = d.value;
    var diameter = v.value;
    var result = (Math.PI * (height * height) * (diameter / 100));
    console.log (result);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Height<h4>
<input id = 'd'></input>
<h4>Diameter<h4>
<input id = 'v'></input>
<button  onClick "calculate()" type = "submit">Calculate</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you mean "volume", which is `pi*radius^2*height`, ie. `Math.PI * diameter/2 * diameter/2 * height`. Your code is currently attempting `pi*height^2*diameter/100` which makes no sense.

Comment: Why use variables named 'd' for height and 'v' for diameter when calculating volume - wouldn't h, d, and v (rather than the ambiguous 'result') respectively be less confusing?

Comment: `square root of a cylinder` ... first you need the hypotenuse of the tangent multiply that by the angle of the derivative

Answer (score 0):

it’s easier:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate(){
        var d = document.getElementById('d').value,
            /* calc radius */
            r = (d / 2),
            /* calc area */
            A = (Math.PI * Math.pow(r, 2));
        console.log (A);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>Diameter<h4>
        <!-- input is selfclosing: -->
        <input id="d" />
        <!-- don’t forget the equal sign after onclick -->
        <button onclick="calculate()" type="button">Calculate</button>
    </body>
</html>
```